# Parallel Request via postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have 10 POST requests in a collection and it doesn't have any dependency on each request. When I tried to execute the collection it was **running sequentially** and it will be time-consuming. As all the requests are independent of each other, Is it possible to execute the 10 POST requests in parallel so that it saves a lot of time.

Is it possible via postman or do I need to look for other tools or any workaround in postman?

Answer (score 1):

As described on this page: [parallelly request source](https://community.postman.com/t/how-can-i-run-simultaneous-request-parallely/3797)

It is necessary to create an sh file to execute the queries in parallel

```
newman run postman/smoke-test/collection.json -e postman/smoke-test/environments/staging.json
```

You can learn what is Newman in this page: [newman doc](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/)